# get value checkbox in zk

Tags: zk, zk-grid

i have a grid with list checkbox

```
    <div height="200px">
<grid id ="actListBox" model="@bind(vm.actions)" >
<template name="model">
<row style=" width:200px !important; ">
    <cell rowspan="5" align="left" >
      <checkbox style="height: 70px; width:1000px; overflow: auto;   margin-left:10px;" 
      label="${each.action_name}" id ="${each.actionid}" value ="${each.actionid}"  />
     </cell>
</row>
</template>
</grid>
<span>
<checkbox label="Check all" value ="checkall" id="chkAll"/>
</span>
</div>
```

and now i want get all value of checkbox but i can't found anyway
please help me
thanks all

Comment: Could you add code for `actions` class?

Comment: it's class have list actionid and action_name and now i want get value of all checkbox

Comment: values of *all* checkbox are all your actionid, this is not clear sorry

Comment: sorry,yes, but i haven't anyway to get them and can you help me

Comment: Here's a [ZK fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/t1jjml/5-Stack-overflow-18223179) showing how to "check all"

Comment: thanks you but my problem that i have a button when i clicked button i can got all id or value of checkbox that i checked. sorry because this is confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in your composer get checked Ids by iterating over actions:

```
@Command
public void checkedIds(final Event e){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Checked Ids: ");
    for (final Action action : actions) {
        if (action.getChecked()) {
            builder.append(action.getId()).append(' ');
        }
    }
    Messagebox.show(builder.toString());      
}
```

I updated the [ZK fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/t1jjml/6-Stack-overflow-18223179).

Comment: i got error when click button or checkbox   
Unknown exception: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: The fiddle I provided is working correctly so you must have something wrong in your code. Feel free to put your non working code in a fiddle (relevant parts) and ask for more help